# Optimal control problem - Hamiltonian won't work

Tags: calculus-of-variations, control-theory, optimal-control

Let the following optimal control problem $(r>0)$:

$$\max \int_0^T\ln q(t)\exp(-rt)dt$$

$$x(0)=s \quad \text{and} \quad x'(t)=-q(t)$$

My idea : let $\lambda \in C^1[0,T]$

then $\mathcal{H}(t,x,q,\lambda)=\ln q\exp(-rt)+\lambda(-q)$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial q}=0 \implies \exp(-rt)/q(t)=\lambda(t)$$ 
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x}=-\lambda'(t) \quad \text{implies} \quad \lambda'(t)=0 \quad \text{implies} \quad \lambda(t)=0 \text{ (since }\lambda(T)=0) $$
Then we'll have : $\exp(-rt)/q(t)=0 \implies 1/q(t)=0 $

I'm stuck there !

Comment: This is true. Your cost function will achieve its maximum at $q(t)=\infty$. You have to modify the problem statement to make it meaningful.

Comment: Does it even make sense to maximize the control effort over time? You will have to reformulate the problem to make sense.

Comment: @Dmitry do you mean I should modify the integrant ?

Comment: In your current formulation, the cost function and the system dynamics are effectively decoupled. You can see this from $\lambda=0$: the dynamics disappear from the Hamiltonian. You should connect both components either by including in the integrand a term depending on $x$ or  by setting a condition on the right end of the trajectory: $x(T)=x_1$. The way you reformulate the problem should follow from its interpretation.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you, helpful idea.